# Django forms ChoiceField: how to add data attributes to input radios?

Tags: django, django-forms, custom-data-attribute

I have a form with a choicefield:

```
   class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
        shipping_method = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

How can I add data attributes to every choice? Something like:

```
<ul id="id_shipping_method">
   <li>
       <label for="id_shipping_method_0">
       <input class="form-control" id="id_shipping_method_0" name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="C" data-method="courier"> Express courier</label></li>
   <li>
      <label for="id_shipping_method_1">
      <input checked="checked" class="form-control" id="id_shipping_method_1" name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="yy" data-method="shop">In shop</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: are you asking how to provide different `data-method`'s for each entry? shouldn't these methods be the `value`s?

Comment: No, because I need data attributes JS side: when I click on a radio, if method is equal to 'by-hand' I have to disable shipping address.
I can't edit values because I don't manage server side..

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Reread the question, updated a few things

A bit messy, but this should get you on the right track. You need to override some of the rendering components of the RadioSelect.

```
from django import forms

CHOICES = (('C','Express courier'),('yy','In shop'), ('h','By hand'))

class MyRadioChoiceInput(forms.widgets.RadioChoiceInput):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        method = {'C': 'courier', 'yy': 'shop', 'h': 'hand'}.get(self.choice_value)
        self.attrs['data-method'] = method

class MyRadioFieldRenderer(forms.widgets.ChoiceFieldRenderer):
    choice_input_class = MyRadioChoiceInput

class MyRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    renderer = MyRadioFieldRenderer

class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    shipping_method = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=MyRadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Example:

```
a = CheckoutForm()
for x in a:
    print(x)
```

Result:

```
<ul id="id_shipping_method">
<li><label for="id_shipping_method_0"><input class="form-control" data-method="courier" id="id_shipping_method_0" name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="C" /> Express courier</label></li>
<li><label for="id_shipping_method_1"><input class="form-control" data-method="shop" id="id_shipping_method_1" name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="yy" /> In shop</label></li>
<li><label for="id_shipping_method_2"><input class="form-control" data-method="hand" id="id_shipping_method_2" name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="h" /> By hand</label></li>
</ul>
```